# How to run mongodb on Linux Server

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have server  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I downloaded  http://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.5.tgz , and extract it on server , 
when I go to 
cd mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.5 
cd bin 
and enter 
./mongod

I get error :  Floating exception

Can someone help me to install mongodb on linux server ?

Also I tried same thing on http://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-2.4.5.tgz , but get same error ...

Comment: which distro are you using?

Comment: Floating exception? I don't think I have actually seen something like that from mongodb, can you show use exactly what it looks like?

Comment: here is prinscreen http://postimg.org/image/ly9dq7zub/

Comment: same thing for  mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.5

Comment: Aha this is a C++ error, what c++ compiler are you using for Linux, `gcc`?

Comment: I don't have gcc installed, I'm newbi in linux server and similar things .. Maybe i need to install gcc or any other compiler ? How I can  check which compiler I use ..

Comment: sorry, actually i has gcc , it is version 4.1.2

Comment: gcc - dumpmachine is  x86_64-suse-linux

Comment: I'll think about this some more

Comment: Ivan, what version of SUSE is this? I'm guessing SLES10? If thats the case then you will either need to manually compile a statically linked version of MongoDB on your SLES10 machine or upgrade your OS. I suspect that local versions of the libraries MongoDB is linking in from your OS are too old.

Comment: How to check which SUSE I use ?

Comment: I fixed problem with Floating exception , but now when I enter ./mogod , I get errror : ./mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpagent.so.20: cannot op en shared object file: No such file or directory .ANy idea how to fix it ????

Answer (score 1):

Our binary builds don't work with SLES (10) and you need a specific build for this. You will need to compile your own binary.

There are build instructions at: http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-on-linux/

Comment: I fixed problem with Floating exception  , but now when I enter ./mogod , I get errror :  ./mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpagent.so.20: cannot op                                             en shared object file: No such file or directory .ANy idea how to fix it ????

Comment: You didn't say how you fixed the floating point exception. The other error is because you don't have the libnetsnmpagent library. You will have to install that through YaST if it's available in the correct version.

Comment: I download mongodb for distrubution SUSE Linux Enterprise . On my server I have installed SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64) . I downloaded mongodb from link http://downloads.10gen.com/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-subscription-suse11-2.4.5.tgz . But now when I enter command ./mongod . I get error   ./mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpagent.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory   .